# iOS development -- delta updates

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I am working on updating an app I didn't initially write.
Right now the app initially downloads (on the first start) a ZIP file that's around 70MB in size. On top of that, on each start the app checks if there is a newer ZIP file online and updates the local one if neccessary.

With the update, I might want to make changes to that process. I consider it user-unfriendly to let him download the app, then on the first start he has to wait until the actual content ZIP is downloaded.

My idea is to offer an app release that already includes the most recent ZIP in the bundle.
However, deploying app updates then becomes a problem. Updates should never contain the ZIP file because the ZIP file needs to be downloaded within the app (it is changes regularly).

Is there a way to fully seperate the update and initial full app releases?

E.g.

- (Day 1) User A downloads app for the first time, app includes ZIP v1
- (Day 2) ZIP v2 is released. User A receives ZIP v2 within the app.
- (Day 3) User B wants to download the app for the first time. To make sure he gets the most recent ZIP file, the app should already contain ZIP v2. That means that on day 2, the app must have received an update BUT only the "initial installation" file must have been updated. User A should not get an update!
- (Day 4) A smaller update (icon changes) is deployed to both User A and B within the app store, it must not contain any ZIP file.

Comment: It's hard to comment not know what is in the download, but assuming it is all data and it is all changed (i.e. the delta update could not be made considerably smaller if you were to merge rather than replace) then it sounds like your app may be better suited to a design where the data is kept in a middle tier and your app interrogates it . . . just a thought.

Comment: During the apps first installation download the zip from web, then each time the app loads, check for a newer version of the zip using some identifier that you can provide for the zip. If new version is available, download it else leave it be. If you can simply remove the zip at the old location and replace it with the new one, then the problem is solved. Then each time a user registers, he will get the new version.